# Use a Greasemonkey script to install other userscripts

Tags: security, installation, greasemonkey, browser-security

Is it possible to create a Greasemonkey script that can manage other userscripts?
I want to write a userscript that automatically installs a group of other userscripts, given a list of userscript URLs.

Comment: It would also be useful if a userscript could toggle scripts that were already installed (for specific websites).

Comment: This question gave me a couple of very useful answers. Why was it downvoted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this is not possible.  It would be a major security hole if it was.

The best you can do is trigger the install dialog, for each script, and let the user decide if she wanted to install the script.

If you figure a way around these restrictions, please let us know so that we can shut it down, post haste. ;-)

---

---

**To trigger the download dialog:**

1. Get the direct, download URL.
   For example, for [**this script**](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/26062):
   [<sub>(Click for larger image)</sub>[image: Finding download URL]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d57su.gif)

   The download URL is:
   `http://userscripts.org/scripts/source/26062.user.js`.
2. Then your script would trigger the Greasemonkey Install dialog by sourcing that URL with an `<iframe>`.

   Here is **a complete Greasemonkey script** that demonstrates that:

   ```
   // ==UserScript==
   // @name     _Auto popup Greasemonkey Script Install Dialog
   // @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
   // @include  http://stackoverflow.com/faq
   // @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
   // @grant    GM_addStyle
   // ==/UserScript==

   var scriptJS_URL    = "http://userscripts.org/scripts/source/26062.user.js";

   $("body").append (
       '<iframe src="' + scriptJS_URL + '" class="gmImstallIframe"></iframe>'
   );

   GM_addStyle ( "                                 \
       iframe.gmImstallIframe {                    \
           width:                  1px;            \
           height:                 1px;            \
           border:                 none;           \
       }                                           \
   " );
   ```
3. **Important:**  There currently seems to be a bug with Greasemonkey (circa version 1.5).  The <kbd>Install</kbd> button works, but the <kbd>Show Script Source</kbd> button appears to be busted for cross-domain scripts.

   [image: Greasemonkey install pop-up]

Comment: Specifically, how can you trigger the installation dialog for a specific script? That would be a reasonable solution, if it were possible.

Comment: Google Chrome no longer allows userscripts to be installed from external websites, but there may be ways around this restriction: http://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2664769&p=crx_warning I'll try to find a way to get this script to work properly in Google Chrome as well as Firefox.

Comment: Using `window.open("http://userscripts.org/scripts/source/26062.user.js")` seems to work in Google Chrome (using Tampermonkey), but for Firefox, the method that you suggested may be better.

Comment: `window.open` is fine, but it's often blocked by the user's settings and/or extensions.

Comment: `window.open`, an `<iframe>`, and *maybe* a [cross-browser extension](http://crossrider.com/) are the only cross-browser techniques for this. To use the iframe technique from Chrome, you have to [revert Chrome's new settings](http://superuser.com/a/450904/41023). ... PS: This question gave no indication that Chrome or cross-browser was applicable. ;-)  The "Greasemonkey" tag implies Firefox-only unless Tampermonkey and/or Chrome is stated in the question or tags.

Answer (score 2):

In Firefox you can call the URL to the userscripts in a hidden frame to fluently create installment popups. Thats the closest you can get.

Doesn't work for Chrome-users anyway, and your real cause, to bypass that installation dialog, is - of course - not possible.

Comment: How can you call the URL in a hidden frame in Firefox?

Comment: Simply append `<iframe src="http://website/userscript.user.js" style="width:1px; height:1px; position:absolute; top:-200px;"></iframe>` to the body of the website the user is on.